# MVC 6 HTTP 500 error on blank app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am attempting to follow [this](http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.org/projects/mvc/en/latest/migration/migratingfrommvc5.html) tutorial.

I have got to the step where I have added the `HomeController.cs` and the corrosponding `Index.cshtml`. When I run the application it just loads a blank page, it's hitting the Index action on the `HomeController` and returning the view. If I take a look at the Http request I am getting:

> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

I cannot seem to find out why.

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }   


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }

        // Entry point for the application.
        public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
    }
```

**project.json**

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",

  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Web.Administration": "7.0.0.0"
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
}
```

**Update**

This is the exception I am getting:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.ILibraryExporter' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.RoslynCompilationService'.
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.PopulateCallSites(ServiceProvider provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)

Comment: There could be an error within the Index.cshtml? Is there no error in the output window or when you debug the application?

Comment: @Pilatus The index.cshtml only contains 1 line `<h1>Hello World!</h1> and when debugging, I cannot see any error in the output window.

Comment: Just to be sure the quote ( ` ) in front of <h1>hello world!</h1> is not in the file right?

Comment: @Pilatus Sorry, it was suppose to be `markdown`

Comment: @JamieR you can enable excepions on the page just add app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); on the Configure method

Comment: @hjgraca thanks, I added the exception

Answer (score 0):

Based on the exception have a look at this issue in github https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/515 Looks like you might not be running the same `dnx` version you have in `project.json`, run `dnvm list` and check if the version in use is the same from `project.json`, if not the same run `dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-final`

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case. It does seem to be working now after. I added a project to the global.json and it works...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In my case my Index.cshtml file was wrong. 
I had

```
@{Hello there !!!}
```

instead of

```
@{}Hello there !!!
```

Your issue might be something completely different. Are you using a Layout file ?

Comment: Yes, The issue is resolved now. I think I added a `global.json` file to the project and it resolved it. Not sure why. The issue is different. My issue is not a Razor syntax issue.